# Why Mitternacht, not Mittnacht

Tags: etymology, gender

I was wondering, middle of the day is *Mittag*, middle of the week is *Mittwoch*, but why midnight is called *Mitternacht!*

I searched a little, and found the explanation behind middle of the week being [Mittwoch](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/18466/5422). Since both *Woche* and *Nacht* are feminine, why is midnight called *Mitternacht?*

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that /Mittnacht/ is a pretty common surname in Germany - a weak proof for the existence of that word in former times. I also happen to own am astronomy book from 1625 that uses /Mittnacht/ as a synonym for /Mitternacht / which proves the decision was close.

Comment: Google Books holds a nice example https://books.google.de/books?id=fgFaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=mittnacht&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=mittnacht&f=false p.47

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word *Mitternacht* is some centuries younger than *Mittwoch* and *Mittag*. *Mitternacht* derives from 14th century phrases such as *vor mitter nahte* (‘before middle night’), where *mitter* is an adjective in dative singular. By [reanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebracketing), the new noun *mitternaht* developed. (See Pfeifer’s *Etymologisches Wörterbuch*, [via DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Mitternacht).)

Comment: I am wondering if the root of this root was "Mitte der Nacht"?

Comment: @TheBlastOne: What do you mean by that, _the root of this root_?

Comment: @chirlu i think, it is *root of this word* !

Comment: @chirlu is it *vor mitter nahte* or *vor mitter na**c**hte*, and *new noun mitternaht* or *new noun mitterna**c**ht* ?

Comment: @MAKZ: Those are just spelling variants. In Middle High German, the /x/ sound is usually written _h_.

Comment: well, as @TheBlastOne has asked, was it derived from *Mitte der Nacht* ?

Comment: @MAKZ: Not really; as I say above, the _Mitter-_ part was originally an adjective (which no longer exists in German, it was replaced by _mittlerer_ etc.). The noun _Mitte_ is of course related to both.

Comment: @chirlu, that makes sense, and answers my question-in-a-comment, thanks.

Comment: @chirlu, yeah, I meant "root of this word". Saw it just now, but cannot edit comment anymore

Answer (score 13):

In both etymological dictionaries that I have available (one of them [here](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=mitternacht); as well as Kluge, 24. edition), it is mentioned that *Mitternacht* is derived from prepositional phrases that were used as adverbials.

In Middle High German there seems to have been an adjective *mitt(e)* whose strong (used without article) dative singular feminine form was formed by means of an *er*-suffix just as in Modern Standard German. From expressions such as Middle High German *ze mitter nachte*, lit. 'at middle night', *middle* corresponding to an adjective in the MHG constructions (unlike English where it just occurs as a noun), the noun *Mitternacht* was derived by dropping the preposition.

Comment: Your answer also seems to be correct. thanks for the explanation.